# Using PHP within JS for $redirectlocation and .$_POST

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've looked and my tweaks won't work (noob) but I've tried!

I have a custom login for cPanel Webmail at a secured port and would like the error message to populate at the custom login page rather than redirecting to the default ports generic login page.

Here's the code I found which should work perfectly except I'm using Wordpress and experiencing the headers already sent error.  I tried to include the pluggable.php as this has worked with plugins I've written in the past for Wordpress admin area, but I cannot get the error resolved public frontend.

```
Username: <input type="text" name="user" value="" size="20" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size="20" /><br />
<div style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="domain" value="emajenweb.webserversystems.com"/>
<select name="port">
  <option selected="selected" value="2096"></option>
</select>    
</div>
<?php
        if($_POST['domain'] && $_POST['user'] && $_POST['pass'] && !($_GET['failed'] == "1")) {
            $port = $_POST['port']; // sets the port number to login to
            // Get the protocol to use for this connection
            switch($port) {
              case '2096': // Secure Webmail
                $protocol = 'https://';
                break;
            }
          // Build the URL
          $redirectlocation = $protocol.$_POST['domain'].':'.$port.'/login/?user='.$_POST['username'].'&pass='.$_POST['pass'].'&failurl='.$_POST['failurl'];
          header ("Location: ".$redirectlocation); // Send URL
        } else {
          $error = 1;
          header ("Location: ".$_POST['failurl']); // Send URL if all neede information is not provided
        }
        ?>
```

The code I have problems with is:

```
header ("Location: ".$redirectlocation); // Send URL
        } else {
          $error = 1;
          header ("Location: ".$_POST['failurl']); // Send URL if all neede information is not provided
```

Given the header already sent error, I am hoping to change the header location values to javascript but I fail...

I have the form working but not as desired with failure messages propagating at the custom login page.

[Webmail Login](http://iemajen.com/webmail-login/)

Answer (score 0):

Error header already sent is a pretty common error. This is caused by... well... header already sent. Header is sent when you send response to server. In your case, it is the:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="user" value="" size="20" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size="20" /><br />
<div style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="domain" value="emajenweb.webserversystems.com"/>
<select name="port">
  <option selected="selected" value="2096"></option>
</select>    
</div>
```

So... how to fix this? Very simple. Just move your processing script BEFORE you send response:

```
<?php
        if($_POST['domain'] && $_POST['user'] && $_POST['pass'] && !($_GET['failed'] == "1")) {
            $port = $_POST['port']; // sets the port number to login to
            // Get the protocol to use for this connection
            switch($port) {
              case '2096': // Secure Webmail
                $protocol = 'https://';
                break;
            }
          // Build the URL
          $redirectlocation = $protocol.$_POST['domain'].':'.$port.'/login/?user='.$_POST['username'].'&pass='.$_POST['pass'].'&failurl='.$_POST['failurl'];
          header ("Location: ".$redirectlocation); // Send URL
        } else {
          $error = 1;
          header ("Location: ".$_POST['failurl']); // Send URL if all neede information is not provided
        }
?>
Username: <input type="text" name="user" value="" size="20" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size="20" /><br />
<div style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="domain" value="emajenweb.webserversystems.com"/>
<select name="port">
  <option selected="selected" value="2096"></option>
</select>    
</div>
```

You should refer to this SO thread for more information: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)